# Using Firebase authentication in mobile app

Tags: spring-security, flutter

I want to make sure the way I'm authenticating users is correct.  Here is what I am doing:

1. I have a flutter app. When users send API request to my server, I am storing a clientKey-secret (base64 encoded) in the code itself.  This is sent to my server in a "Authentication" header, along with grant-type of "client_credentials".  A token is returned which doesn't expire and can be used for most read operations.
2. For write operations, I first get the user credentials via a form.  I then have another clientKey-secret (base64 encoded) which is sent to server in "Authentication" header along with username/password with grant-type of "password". Another token is returned, which is used for all write operations.

My question is:

These base64 encoded strings are stored as property values. They can probably be easily decompiled and obtained by a hacker.  But where can I store them that will be safe?  Is there another approach I should be using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uses JWT because this form is very dangerus for security

Answer (score 0):

Check flutter_secure_storage package for safe storage.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage